# How to change Kendo UI grid div id ((default 'grid') like grid1, grid2) dynamically by Kendo UI PHP Wrappers

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to add multiple grid in same page using kendo ui tabstrip loading by ajax. its worked but when i add multiple grid, because of same div id ("grid") its just displaying first div. is there any option to change div id in PHP Wrappers. Or any other ways to load multiple grid using tabstrip ajax loading option.

like `<div id="grid1">`
another `<div id="grid2">`

Answer (score 1):

Grid id is equal to grid name, so based to [Kendo Basic grid example](http://demos.telerik.com/php-ui/grid/index) you can set it like this:

```
$gridNum = 1;
```

And in grid generating code:

```
$grid = new \Kendo\UI\Grid('grid' + $gridNum++);
```

Answer (score 0):

Default in kendo ui php wrappers

```
$grid = new \Kendo\UI\Grid('grid');
```

Just change the grid as your desire like

```
$grid = new \Kendo\UI\Grid('employee');
$grid = new \Kendo\UI\Grid('order');
```

Thank you [j4ro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3197316/j4ro)